# Site Collection Read-Only lock renders 'View in Browser' fail

Tags: 2016, read-only, quota, lock, office-online-server

We are on SharePoint 2016 with Office Online Server 2016. We have sites that we'd like to lock in read-only mode (per CA), but upon doing so will make the viewing the document in the browser view fail with:

> "There's a configuration problem preventing us from getting your
>   document. If possible, try opening this document in Microsoft Word."
>   [image]

We'd like to ability for users to still view documents in a site that is read-only locked. Seems like we can't have both, unless I'm missing something...?

EDIT: Looking more into it, if I take a site out of read-only, and browse to it, my displayname is updated from domain\LOGINNAME to "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME", and if I put the read-only lock on it again, I can now view documents in the browser correctly.

Question now becomes, **how can I automatically do that for all my users** (so they don't have to navigate to the site first)?